# Azure Functions - AAD Authentication Breaks Development Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I've added AAD authentication to an Azure Functions App with a custom domain name and SSL bindings. When I turn this on I start to get errors such as:

```
"The function runtime is unable to start"

"Unauthorized - https://myfunctionsapp.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/keys"

"Unauthorized - https://myfunctionsapp.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/myfunc/keys"
```

However, if I change the settings to allow anonymous access if an unauthorized request is received then it works fine.

This appears to be the same as an [existing answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627522/azure-function-app-authentication-breaks-development-portal) which was answered with a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/794) which has since been closed as resolved. So this would suggest that the bug has come back or there's something different with my setup (possibly the custom domain?)

The workaround suggested in the original question would still work, but ideally I'd like to see if I can get the functionality working as expected.

Comment: Added appropriate people on the GitHub issue. This may be a bug... we are investigating. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MarieHoeger

Comment: are you running in an ASE (specifically, an ILB ASE) by chance?

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid not

Comment: Great, thanks :) if you were, there is a known issue. Still looking into the issue, thanks for your patience!